# Real time stock watch with node.js angular and socket.io backend mysql and php

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I am working on new project to display an online stock price screen for a user. We already have this in a combination of php, MySQL and AJAX, but it is very slow and lots of requests are generated on the server. So I want to change the technology.

I have the database in MySQL. One process is already updated: the last price of stock in my database. I fetch those records and display them in the screen. After searching Google, I feel I have to use socket.io, node.js and angularjs. After this I am planning the following:

1. Front End in angular.js
2. Socket.io with nodes.js
3. Nodes.js
4. Restful API call initiated on nodes.js every 10 seconds for `page.php`. This page will fetch all symbols of market (around 1000) from the MySQL database and send back a json object. (Can I directly call a MySQL query from node.js and received the json object, and will this reduce the php in-between?)
5. Socket.io emits this query to every client connect on the site.
6. Then the angular front-end will display only the symbol which is selected by the user and highlight the changes on the screen.

I have the following problems, as I have limited knowledge of the above technologies.

1. How do I receive the json object from socket.io into angular.js?
2. How can I make the logic in the angular page to display only the symbol which user selected from a 1000 symbols response and highlight the change price field only?
3. How will I connect three and server with MySQL or php?
4. One thing is read for middle ware i can use the expressJS.AS I want my front end in AngularJS how can i fit the express in between Angular and socket.io and node.js

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting your grammar, but some issues remain unclear. Please check if I did not inadvertently change the meaning of your problem explanation or questions, and please clarify question #4 some more.

Comment: Thanks for editing. You did not changed meaning of my question. q4 I read and feel i can user middleware inbetween node.js and angular the expresss. Can this will help me in any way?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to include socket.io client code on your site, and here is a good example how to turn an external library like socket.io into a service http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/
2. I think that the best solution here would be to subscribe via socket.io only the element user wants to see i.e. websockets for selected element and pooling every minute or so for other elements to not generate that much of a traffic on sockets

user opens element A

```
socket.emit('subscribe', {add: 'A'})
```

then user switch to element B

```
socket.emit('subscribe', {add: 'B', remove: 'A'})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is good example. I only want to use socket.io and do not want to use any module like  angular seed etc. I want full control on program